# How to change uploaded file permissions for new files automatically

Tags: php, plesk, mediatemple, virtuozzo

I recently moved a wordpress site from media temple's gs to their dedicated virtual server.

The file structure changed when I upload files.  The permissions automatically upload as 644 and I'd like to change this.  Where should I look to change this, the php.ini file or somewhere ont he server settings?  It uses plesk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to find a way to change your umask.  You might have to talk to your server administrator about it, if you don't have shell access.

Comment: I do have shell access - I'm going to find the syntax now - Thanks!